# Mass Node Update (e.g., disable comments for all nodes of a given content type)

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to mass update nodes from, say, "Comments Read/Write" to "Comments Disabled" for all nodes of a certain content type?

I changed the Content Type setting and that worked for all the other nodes types, except for a certain Node type that has given us problems in the past.

Thx

Answer (score 5):

There's a module called [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

I never tried to do it, but I think you can write your own operations for this module pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks.  We do have that and it allows me to filter the options, just not the mass update of turning off "Comments" that I need - that I can see.

Comment: The VBO description says "Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used." You have to code this action in PHP. Since this would call all necesary update/save hooks on the nodes as well this would be a clean solution.

Comment: VBO for D7 allows you to use the "Modify entity values" action to change the comment status without coding.

In D6, you can always use the "Execute PHP code" action to change each node.

Answer (score 2):

Not for the weak of heart, and this bypasses the chance for hooks to fire on the node save / update as well as revisioning, but I usually do this with direct queries.

```
UPDATE node
SET comment = 0
WHERE type = 'some_type'
```

should do it.  Make sure you take a [backup](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) to be safe.  If you are on Drupal 7, the comment status is also in `node_revision`, so you need to do

```
UPDATE node_revision nr 
INNER JOIN node n ON n.vid = nr.vid 
SET nr.comment = 0
WHERE n.type = 'some_time'
```

as well.

Answer (score 1):

Disable comments here first:

```
structure->content types->{node_type}->edit->comment settings
```

To update the nodes use hook_update below:

```
/**
 * Disable comments on node_type
 */
function hook_update_N(&$sandbox) {
  $content_type = 'node_type';

  // Initialize batch.
  if (!isset($sandbox['total'])) {
    $query = db_select('node');
    $query->addExpression('COUNT(*)');
    $query->condition('type', $content_type);

    $sandbox['total'] = $query->execute()->fetchField();
    $sandbox['progress'] = 0;

    if (empty($sandbox['total'])) {
      $sandbox['#finished'] = 1;
      return t('No %type nodes exist in database.', array('%type' => $content_type));
    }
  }

  // Get and update nodes.
  $nids = db_select('node')
    ->fields('node', array('nid'))
    ->condition('type', $content_type)
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids, NULL, TRUE);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $node->comment = 1; // I set comments as 1 where value of 2 enables the comments.
      node_save($node);   // Re-save the node.
    }
  }

  // Increment & check progress.
  $sandbox['progress'] += count($nids);
  if (empty($nids) || $sandbox['progress'] >= $sandbox['total']) {
    $sandbox['#finished'] = 1;
    return t('Updated @count nodes.', array('@count' => $sandbox['progress']));
  }
  else {
    $sandbox['#finished'] = $sandbox['progress'] / $sandbox['total'];
  }
}
```

Do not forget to replace **'node_type'** to your node type.

Comment: What is a node_type? You mean content_type? Also this didn't work for me. I'm trying to unpublish content and the only hook that works are the views hooks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Drupal 6 solution that does not involve SQL queries or running your own PHP code via VBO or custom module, there is also [Mass Change](https://drupal.org/project/mass_change). It allows you to change statuses, including comment status, for all nodes of a particular content type.